# How do I prevent my camera/lens from focusing on only a subject?

Tags: autofocus, focus, depth-of-field, 50mm

I have a Canon 70D and am using a 50mm lens. I want to prevent it from focusing on a subject all the time. Instead, I want everything to be in focus like you get with a kit lens (18-135 etc.).

I have turned autofocus off, but this then requires me to manually focus on the subject rather than having everything in focus.

How do I achieve this? Is there any other settings on my camera I need to enable/disable?

Comment: I know that may not sound like this is a duplicate of that question, but actually it is - if you want a large amount of scene in focus, it's the aperture you care about, not the focusing or the focus mode.

Answer (score 2):

Hummmm.... well this will be a little bit hard to explain, but if you'll read what I'll link and write then you'll understand it.

You are a beginner, isn't it? :-)

You want

> everything to be in focus like you get on a kit lens (18-135 etc).

1. First you must understand the basic notions about Depth of Field (DoF) and Aperture. If you already know these things, then you can skip to point 2. If not, read & study this link:

http://digital-photography-school.com/understanding-depth-field-beginners/

2. You did not mention what 50mm lens but from the 'mood' of your question and from the fact that you say 'a 50mm lens' I conclude that we speak about a variant of EF 50mm F/1.8 (or perhaps F/1.4?). This, combined with lens' focal length and with the fact that most probably you shoot in 'Full Auto'/Program mode means that most probably you have a (very) thin DoF (due of big apertures) which separates your "subject" (as you say) from the background.
3. OTOH, 18-135 has a much bigger DoF in Full Auto/Program mode(s) because its aperture varies from 3.5 to 5.6 (IIRC), thing which is combined with the corresponding focal length at each aperture value. That's why you see 'everything in focus' with the kit lens.

After you read (and understand) each points above, the solution is simple:

1. Switch the camera to Av mode.
2. Using the camera's main dial, set the aperture to the desired value in order to have everything in focus (F/11, 16, 22 - depending on your subject size and distance from it).

Hint: You need (a lot of) light and/or quality trade-of (due of High ISO) in order shoot with these apertures.

Comment: Yes I am a beginner, and it seems like this is the solution. I do not have my camera on me right now but I will confirm it and give you a upvote if this can lead to the solution which I am confidence it will :) And yes its canon 50mm F/1.8

Answer (score -3):

You can switch your AF to "One Shot" Mode. This will prevent continuous focussing.
It will focus once you press the trigger halfway and then stay at that focal length until you release and press again.

Comment: He does NOT have problems with choosing the wrong subject (or 'focus hunting/jumping'). He wants to have "everything" in focus.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood the question. thx for the clarification.